# Does this set of infinite binary sequences have positive probability?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random

The AMM article ["What is a random sequence?"](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/news/monthly046-063.pdf) argues (at the end of Sec. 2) that if, from the set of all binary sequences, we remove those (countably many) that have "computable regularities", then the remaining (uncountable) set must *still* contain uncountably many "non-random" sequences. It takes as an example the set of infinite binary sequences $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ that satisfy $x_{2n} = x_{2n+1}$ for all $n \ge 1$, which are considered too "locally ordered" to be regarded as random. Since there are uncountably many such sequences, uncountably many will remain after any countable subset is removed. The article concludes from this that it is inadequate to define random sequences as those not containing "computable regularities".

EDIT (my objection is fallacious): <s>But it seems to me that that conclusion of inadequacy would not follow from the example if the above-mentioned set has Bernoulli$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ product measure equal to $0$--as I suspect is the case. (*Any* otherwise "bad" set seems innocuous if it has probability $0$.)</s>

**Question**: What is the probability, i.e., the Bernoulli$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ product measure, of the set of infinite binary sequences $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ that satisfy $x_{2n} = x_{2n+1}$? In particular, does this set have positive probability?

Comment: I don't know what your objection is.  You can't rule out any event of nonzero probability, precisely because that event has nonzero probability of occurring in a random sequence.  You can rule out an event of probability $0$ **because** it has probability $0$.  Yes, the event $x_{2n} = x_{2n+1}$ for all $n$ has probability $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - Perhaps there's some confusion about "ruling out" an event. My objection to the argument in the article is that a "bad" set of probability $0$ is innocuous precisely **because** it has probability $0$ (in spite of it being uncountable), whereas the article treats it as significant instead of innocuous, merely because it's uncountable.

Comment: "the article treats it as significant instead of innocuous, merely because it's uncountable." No. Rather the author points out that getting rid if lawless sequences is not enough because the set $L$ of lawless sequences is at most countable and there exists some uncountable set $D$ of sequences we would want to get rid as well (that is, the sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_{2n}=x_{2n+1}$ for every $n$). No measure is involved here, only un/countability to argue that $D\subseteq L$ is impossible.

Comment: @Did - My objection is that if $P(D)=0$ (which, as you say, the article neglects to consider), then $D$ is not significant even though it is uncountable -- so getting rid of it unnecessary. The article treats $D$ as significant merely because it is uncountable.

Comment: Once again: the author does not use probability measure at this point, instead they merely invoke the fact that D is uncountable to prove that D is not included in L, hence getting rid of L only is not satisfactory.

Comment: @did - Once again: the fact that $D$ is not included in $L$ is unimportant if $P(D)=0$, in spite of $D$ being uncountable.

Comment: Apparently, you did not read my comment. So be it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40006/discussion-between-r-e-s-and-did).

Comment: Sorry for the stubborn confusion -- I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is contained in the events that contain a finite number of these restrictions. The event with the first $k$ such restrictions has probability $2^{-k}$. Since the probability of your event is bounded above by these probabilities, it must be $0$. (To be rigorous, you might also want to show that it's measurable; I'm assuming that.)

Comment: How are you ordering these restrictions, so as to speak of the first $k$ of them? It's interesting that your first two sentences seem to imply that any similar set invoking finitely many restrictions (re the "bad" sets) will have probability $0$, in which case the article's argument seems even more tenuous to me.

Comment: @r.e.s.: Perhaps I misunderstood something. I was ordering them according to $n$: First $x_2=x_3$, then $x_4=x_5$, etc. I don't understand why you now talk about a set invoking finitely many restrictions. This set has infinitely many restrictions; I just considered them one at a time.

Comment: Oops -- I meant to write "infinitely many", in such a way that your approach applies to them as well.